# How to loop over multiple Pandas DataFrames using the filter function?

Tags: python

So I have multiple data frames that I am attempting to loop over.

I have created a list using the following code:

`data_list = [df1, df2, df3]`

After that I would like to filter out a predefined range of numbers in the column 'Firm_Code' in each data frame.

So far, I am able to filter out firms with a respective code between 6000 and 6999 for a single data frame as follows:

```
FFirms = range(6000,7000)
Non_FFirms = [b for b in df1['Firm_Code'] if b not in FFirms]
df1 = df1.loc[df1['Firm_Code'].isin(Non_FFirms)]
```

Now I would like to loop over the `data_list`. My first try looks like the following:

```
for i in data_list:
     i = i.loc[i.Firm_Code.isin(Non_FFirms)]
```

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the list of dataframes, you can concat all the data frames into a single dataframe.

```
data_df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],ignore_index=True)
```

In case you need identification from which dataframe you have fetched the value you can add a new column say 'Df_number'.

using `data_df` you can you can filter the data

```
FFirms = range(6000,7000)
Non_FFirms = [b for b in df1['Firm_Code'] if b not in FFirms]
filtered_data_df = data_df.loc[data_df['Firm_Code'].isin(Non_FFirms)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I need to run it on all dataframes. Basically what I need is to define a function and then sequentially apply it to all dataframes within the list.

Comment: I am still not clear with '...need to run it on all dataframes', what my suggestion was that instead of looping for each df in the list, comibile all df at once and apply your filter. In case you need the identification that from which df your data is filtered from you can add a new column for the same as mentioned.